# Changing the brightness on the Lenovo T410

Tags: 14.04, brightness, lenovo

I can't change the brightness on my lenovo T410 laptop. I tried changing it from the system settings and using fn+Home, but both didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The fix here:

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T510

worked for me after a restart. Just be sure to backup your xorg.conf file beforehand (you can find it in /etc/X11/)

My xorg.conf looks like this now in its entirety, and it works fine:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Comment: With Kubuntu 18.04 I had to generate an xorg.conf, using nvidia-settings program.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me too on a T410 with NVS 3100M graphics. Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia with NVIDIA 340.104 Driver.

First updated the BIOS to version 1.45

Second selected NVIDIA's driver in "Update Manager", and rebooted

Third discovered that I did not have an "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" file

1) Opened the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" application

2) Clicked on "X Server Display Configuration" (in left panel)

3) Clicked on "Save to X Configuration File" (bottom right)

4) Saved config file to "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

5) Edited (as Administrator) "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

6) Added 2 lines from Hunter's post:

```
    Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
    Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

7) Saved and rebooted